# Angle for ruler falling off the table

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, torque

When you place a ruler on the edge of the table so that one end is hanging off the table, and you apply a force to the hanging end with your hand, at what angle (angle between ruler and table) will the ruler fall?

I've identified the forces acting on the ruler and the position of the centre of mass; however, I'm a bit stuck attempting to devise a mathematical equation to measure this angle. I'm trying to find a relationship between the angle and the distance from the centre of mass to the pivot point.

Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: The answer has to do with friction and at what point is the force applied overcomes this friction in the direction of slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start with a good diagram indicating all applicable forces applied in a positive sense, relevant dimensions, and points of interest.

[image: fig1]

Here a force $P$ is applied on the end of the ruler downwards, in addition to the weight of the ruler $W$ applied in the center.

The edge contact provides a normal force $N$ and a frictional reaction $F$ that prevents the ruling from sliding off.

If you look at the forces applied in the vertical direction you must counteract the weight and applied force with the vertical component of the normal force and frictional force. On the other hand, the horizontal components must balance out

$$ \begin{aligned}
 -W - P + N \cos \varphi + F \sin \varphi & = 0 \\
  N \sin \varphi - F \cos \varphi & = 0 \\
\end{aligned}$$

The solution to the above is

$$ \begin{aligned}
 F & = (P+W) \sin \varphi \\
 N & = (P+W) \cos \varphi
\end{aligned}$$

The stability limit is reached when $F \gt \mu_S N$ where $\mu_S$ is the coefficient of static friction and from the above you get

$$ \sin \varphi \gt \mu_S \cos \varphi $$

with the solution for the tilt angle

$$  \varphi \gt \arctan( \mu_S) $$

This angle is often called the *critical angle* for friction. It is the same angle something placed on a ramp is going to be sliding down when exceeded.

Comment: Oh, I understand now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is it possible to deduce a relationship between d and angle ?

Comment: In a static sense, _φ_ does not depend on _d_. But if you want more in-depth analysis you need to consider the dynamics of the problem which involves the acceleration of the center of mass and that involves the _d_ parameter.